# C# Get data from website and show it in textbox

Tags: c#, web-scraping

Hello i am pretty new in c# sphere. I want to make a little program that will fetch data from the given page.

It is a fragment of website:

```
<h3 class="filmInfo__header cloneToCast cloneToOtherInfo" data-type="directing-header">reżyseria</h3>
<div class="filmInfo__info cloneToCast cloneToOtherInfo" data-type="directing-info"><a href="/person/Rupert+Sanders-1121101" title="Rupert Sanders" itemprop="director" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"> <span itemprop="url" content="/person/Rupert+Sanders-1121101"></span> <span itemprop="name">Rupert Sanders</span> </a></div>
```

I want to get data from "Data-type="Directing-info" and get a result from title="Rupert Sanders"
Somebody can help me ?

My very simple code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var url = "https://www.filmweb.pl/film/Kr%C3%B3lewna+%C5%9Anie%C5%BCka+i+%C5%81owca-2012-600541";

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            textBox1.Text = (html.Result);
        }
```

Comment: Research Angle Sharp or Html Agility pack

Answer (score 0):

C# or .NET does not offer native HTML parsing functionality. However, there are a handful of libraries which provides HTML parsing functionality. For example, you can use [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/).

First, you need to install it into your project. You can easily install it with NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio if you use it.

[image: NuGet Package Manager with Html Agility Pack]

After that, you can use it like this with your input HTML:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = "https://www.filmweb.pl/film/Kr%C3%B3lewna+%C5%9Anie%C5%BCka+i+%C5%81owca-2012-600541";

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var html = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

    // Create a HtmlDocument and load your HTML into it.
    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html.Result);

    // Find your desired node inside it.
    HtmlNode directingInfoNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@data-type='directing-info']/a");

    // Get the title attribute of that node.
    HtmlAttribute titleAttribute = directingInfoNode.Attributes["title"];

    textBox1.Text = (titleAttribute.Value);
}
```

Of course, you will need to put necessary `using` statement to the top of your file:

```cs
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```